# Problem with selecting data from a database using .NET c# Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, debugging

```
try
{
    //insert data into database
    //check if data already exists
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=DESKTOP-31579CJ\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LoginInformation;Trusted_connection = True;"))
    { 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT User.Username FROM User WHERE Username = '" + Username.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Account created");
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO User (Username,Password) VALUES ('" + Username.Text + "','" + Password.Password + "')", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //clear textboxes
            Username.Text = "";
            Password.Password = "";
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception occured" + ": " + ex.Message);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-31579CJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LoginInformation;Integrated Security=True;User ID = yes; Password = yes");
    //create table if one does not exist
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE User (Username varchar(50), Password varchar(50))", con);
}
```

When I attempt to execute this query I am met with the exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

but I haven't really used C# or SQL that often so I honestly couldn't see the problem -- Any feedback on this code will also be appreciated

Comment: This question has got nothing to do with MySQL. MySQL and SQL Server are two completely separate and different RDBMSes. The fact that you are using `System.Data.SqlClient` types means that you're using SQL Server. If you were using MySQL then you'd have to have referenced their Connector/Net and be using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` types.

Comment: There's no point your actually reading the data from your query. You don't care what the data is; only that it exists. You can just check the `HasRows` property to determine that. In fact, I'd suggest changing your query to produce either a flag that indicates whether any data exists or else a count of matching records. If you use `COUNT` in the SQL then you can call `ExecuteScalar` and check whether the result is zero or greater than zero.

Comment: Your `catch` block is bizarre. You are catching any and every exception and then connecting to the same database and creating a new table?! What if the exception is due to a timeout when executing a query or because the database wasn't found? If you reasonably expect a specific exception for a specific reason then catch that specifically. Any other unexpected exceptions should be caught with a global exception handler and logged before exiting the app. That will enable you to investigate and fix the bug that caused them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked to confirm but I'm guessing that "User" is a reserved word in T-SQL so you would need to escape it:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Username FROM [User] WHERE Username = '" + Username.Text + "'", con);
```

Note that I have removed the table qualifier from the column name. You can include it but it's rather pointless in a statement that involves a single table. If you do include it, you'd need to escape that too.

You'll have to do the same thing in your other SQL too. "Password" may also be a reserved word - it is in Access but I'm not sure about SQL Server.

This is beyond the scope of this question but you really ought to not use string concatenation to insert values into SQL either. It's very bad practice that can lead to various issues, including malicious users potentially corrupting or deleting your entire database. Learn how to use parameters immediately. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on the subject.

Comment: Yeah this seemed to be the problem and it is all working now, Much appreciated and I will also take the formatting into consideration.